# jQuery Preload not dissapearing

Tags: jquery, preloader, preload

I have a preloader in this site: http://exit.santamartastudio.es/ and it happens sometimes it hides the preloader, and some not. I've look for it But don't know why it fails.

UPDATE(Here is the code):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setLoader();
  Here I load the rest of jquery
});



$(window).load(function () {
  hideloader();
});
```

Functions:

```
// Setloader
function setLoader() {
  disable_scroll();
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}
// Hideloader
function hideLoader() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width

  $('#loader img').animate({
    left: '+=' + ((windowWidth/2) + 100)
  }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

  $('#loader span').animate({
    left: '-=' + ((windowWidth/2) + 100)
  }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#loader').fadeOut(800, 'linear', function(){
      enable_scroll();
      $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: can we see your js that loads the preloader?

Comment: Console gives two errors, one is: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hideloader`. Try to use `'use strict';` on top of your JavaScript to get the most STRICT errors so you can best backtrace any errors you have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `hideLoader()` doesn't get triggered correctly. If I type this into my console on Safari;

```
hideLoader();
```

..everything just happens, meaning there's nothing wrong with the actual implementation.

The problem here is that the code is "too late". You have to prioritize that one thing waits for another. Modern browsers load the scripts extremely fast. It might be that the load is even earlier than the function to load. I mostly get `0.0ms` and `0.1ms` load times on the DOM events.

You can try to put your function code inside a jQuery function and to be sure try to put the functions before the ready-state bindings (functions).

There seems to be no other explanation than a too fast triggering ready-state. Try to test with a big picture in the page so your ready state takes longer, you probably will never get the error in that case, as the ready-state will take longer to complete.

Comment: Thanks allendar for your response. Perheps is for my english but I don't really understand what you mean to do. Don't understand "You can try to put your function code inside a jQuery function and to be sure try to put the functions before the ready-state bindings (functions)." I've put all code in a fiddle: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/demssite/KwgX3/).  Thanks in advance